# Usage of "down the road"

Tags: idioms, usage

Instead of *in the future*, can I say *down the road* in the following sentence?

> It can be achieved in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Down the road" is an idiom. If we say something will happen down the road, it will happen in the future.

So the sentence "It can be achieved down the road" is correct; it means that "It can be achieved in the future".

Comment: It looks clear for me too. :)